# Emacs with ESS won't start in El Capitan

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I did install emacs from [here](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/mac/), and it worked perfectly until early today.

my `.bash_profile` looks:

```
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

#—— Alias
alias rm='rm -i'
alias emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

However, when I type:

```
$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
```

while it should point to the alias.

```
$ /usr/bin/emacs -version
GNU Emacs 22.1.1
...
```

This is the default version, which seems to work, but is not the one I'd like to use:

When I type

```
$ emacs -version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
```

Which is the version I would like to use, the modified version with ESS "inside". Now emacs won't even start. For whatever reason, freezes in a white screen while loading. I am on `R version 3.3.1` and the ESS version that comes with the modified version of emacs is `ESS 16.04;`

I start emacs by typing `emacs` in my terminal (`iterm2`). However, not even double-clicking in the dowloaded App will work.

If I install and start the [normal](https://emacsformacosx.com/) version of Emacs, it will start **IF** I comment all set-up related with `R`.

I have tried a fresh installation of R and it won't work either. Has anyone any idea of what is going on?

**EDIT**: I think the problem might be related with El Capitan + ESS, since I have started from a fresh OSX Installation and won't work either.

Comment: Are you saying `/usr/bin/emacs` crashes or just `emacs` crashes? Or do you start Emacs by opening it from the doc bar at the bottom of the screen? Which version are you hoping to use, 22.1.1 or 24.5.1?

Comment: Hi Brian, just `emacs` crashes, and I can't open it whether from the doc or terminal. I hope to use the modified version of `emacs`, 24.5.1. I have added a few edits to improve the quality/clarity of the question.

Comment: If you want to keep debugging it, try `emacs --debug-init`, it should print some stack trace sort of thing when it crashes. But you can probably get a fix faster by reinstalling Emacs and R (I suspect they're bundled incorrectly), try installing Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/ and installing the individual packages by running `M-x list-packages` and selecting them out of the list.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. I actually re-format entirely my Mac over the weekend. I installed R and then emacs and did not work. Then emacs-modified and did not work. I gave up and moved to sublime.